# Access the OpenVR chaperone (Play area boundary box) without having SteamVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, boundary, steamvr

I am trying to get access to the bounding box/Chaperone of my VR project without relying on SteamVR. I am trying to build a framework that works as native as possible to Unity.

In SteamVR one would write:

```
 Valve.VR.OpenVR.Chaperone.ForceBoundsVisible(true);
 // or 
 Valve.VR.OpenVR.Chaperone.ForceBoundsVisible(False);
```

My question is how can I do something similar to this with just the OpenVR package and not the SteamVR plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenVR SDK](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr).

If you are using C#, there is a wrapper lacated at `headers\openvr_api.cs`.

At first you have to load library (`openvr_api.dll`) and init it like this:

```
var error = EVRInitError.None;
OpenVR.Init(ref error, EVRApplicationType.VRApplication_Background)
```

Then simply use it the same way

```
OpenVR.Chaperone.ForceBoundsVisible(true);
```

You can also read `chaperone_info.vrchap` and `steamvr.vrsettings` from `config` folder of Steam. These json files contain information about all universes collision bounds.